# How to avoid all special characters except spaces in a regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am building, AutoComplete editor by using Row Filter and i am using Regex to remove special characters. But spaces are also removed.

Regex :

```
Regex.Replace(currentText, "[^0-9A-Za-z]", ",");
```

I just want to ignore spaces but replace the remaining special characters.

Answer (score 17):

Just add space in your negation character class to skip space to be replaced by a comma.

```
Regex.Replace(currentText, "[^0-9A-Za-z ,]", ",");
```

**PS:** I added comma also in your character class to avoid comma getting replaced by comma.